# How to describe Schema of my object by Open Api 3.0 with @annotation?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

Is it ok to use annotation for this? I don't understand how to use Yaml.

Example:

```
 @Operation(summary = "Get page of top by rating articles by title")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200 successful operation",
                    content = @Content(
                            mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                            schema = @Schema(???)))
    })
     @GetMapping(value = {"/articles/topByRating"})
     @JsonView({JsonViews.Short.class})
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
     public ItemsDto<Article> getArticlesTopByRating(@RequestParam int numberPage, @RequestParam int sizePage) {
        return articleCrud.getTopByRating(numberPage, sizePage);
    }
```

ItemsDto:

```
public class ItemsDto<E> {
    Long total = 0L;
    List<E> items;
}
```

Article:

```
public class Article{
    private Author author;
    private String title;
    private String body;
}
```

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/
Free-Form Objects
"If the dictionary values can be of any type (aka free-form object), use additionalProperties: true:"

```
1.     type: object
2.     additionalProperties: true
```

I will try to use 'ref = myfile.yaml' property into @Schema annotation

Answer (score 0):

The object are converted automatically to Schema by springdoc-openapi.

Note that on your DTOs, you can add the @Schema annotation as well to customise the different fields.